# How the new ScadaLTS UI communicates with tomcat?

Tags: scadalts

I'm following the development of Scada-LTS, but I do not understand how the new UI communicates with tomcat. I can not get past the login screen, I believe it's because I'm not using the default tomcat port. What changes should I make?

Comment: Which version of tomcat and Scada are you using?

Comment: Tomcat 7 and latest version of ScadaLTS